# How to add multiple lines to a file in C++?

Tags: c++, string, file, stream

I am new to C++ and write a little todo list on the console.
I am only able to add one line to a text file but when I try to add more it just won't appear on my text file.

Please take a look what I am doing wrong

```
//output-file stream
    ofstream file;
    file.open("output.txt", std::ios_base::app); //append

    bool isRunning = true;

    while (isRunning) {
        cout << "Please select an action:" << endl;
        cout << "add - adding tasks to the list" << endl;
        cout << "del - deleting tasks to the list" << endl;
        cout << "list - show the list" << endl;
        cout << "x - to exit program" << endl;

        string input;
        cin >> input; 
        string addedTask;

        if (input == "add") {
            cout << "Please enter a task you like to add: " << endl;
            cin.ignore();
            if (std::getline(std::cin, addedTask)) {
                file << addedTask << "\n";
            }
            else {
                cout << "Failed to read line" << endl;
            }
        }
```

Why can I only add one string line? I still can't figure out the problem or am I missing something?

Comment: Why do you repeatedly `.open()` the file?

Comment: if you open the file multiple times, you need to close it as many times.

Comment: I move that line already outside, still not working

Comment: Outside to where?

Comment: outside the while loop

Comment: I edited my post but still have the problem

Comment: Time for a [mcve]

Comment: Are you sure that the input is correct?

Comment: You also need to provide the rest of your loop.

Comment: I tried now without the while loop and it works if I always restart the program it seems to add my inputs... but for some reason with the while loop it just adds the first input and ignores all the other inputs..

Comment: Where's the [mcve]?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try replacing your

```
file << addedTask << "\n";
```

by

```
file << addedTask << endl;
```

I think it should work (for me it's working)

Comment: No, this only forces an immediate flush. It doesn't affect what data ultimately ends up in the file. Though it could be relevant if the OP is trying to observe the file mid-run, that wasn't stated. In general, you want `'\n'` not `endl`.

Comment: When to main function terminates, the `ofstream` file `close()` function is called which flushes any string left to write to the file. So `endl;` shouldn't fix it. We need his full code